# How to fix loading user settings frozen screen?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, coreldraw

So to some up the problem I am having CorelDraw will not start up, while starting up it would freeze on loading user settings and not respond. After searching the corel site I tried the following:

1. Application was uninstalled.
2. Computer was booted in Safe mode.
3. Registry was cleared.
4. Application was reinstalled.

However the problem persists. Has anyone experienced this?

### System:

Windows 7 Ultimate x64
i5 with 8 GB Ram

---

### Edit

The user profile was deleted during un-installation.

Comment: Have you tried to manually delete the application user's profile settings

Comment: I have not where can i find these

Comment: Ok the profile was deleted during un-installation